# Navigation from Activity to previous location (previous tab(fragment) and other Activity)

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin. I faced the problem of the navigation from Activity to previous location. The ArtikelContent Activity can be open by 3 different location which are: 1.Home menu 2.Artikel home - at the "Semua" tab (Fragment Semua) 3. Artikel home - at the "KAT 1" tab (Fragment KAT 1). Im using imageview as a back button on Artikel Content. Im faced the problem to navigate to the previous location before i open the ArtikelContent Activity by using imageview as a button.

This is the code i use on the ArtikelContent.kt Activity for back navigation:

val btnback : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.buttonback)

```
    btnback.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent (this, ArtikelHome::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: Please [paste your code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Already paste the code as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `ArtikelHome` activity in this `btnBack` click listener because of the new Intent. If you want to navigate back to the `ArtikelHome` activity then use `finish()` like this:

```
btnback.setOnClickListener {
    finish()
}
```

It will destroy the `ArtikelContent` activity and you will be navigated to the previous activity in stack which is `ArtikelHome` activity.